# I am looking for a specialist WordPress host

Tags: hosting, hosting-recommendation

I am looking for a host to start my new WordPress site.

The criteria for this is that they must totally/truly specialise in WordPress hosting.

Many companies claim to have a certain expertise in hosting WordPress, but the fact is they just have it installed.

I would like recommendations for hosts in the UK but am open to worldwide offers.

Comment: The only "dedicated" WordPress host I'd consider using is http://page.ly/. Just watch out, there's a ton of resellers out there targeting "wordpress hosting" to make a quick buck.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic that is one of the most expensive options I have seen $20 a month for 5GB and this message didn't install a lot of confidence : ) https://page.ly/signup/offline

Comment: I guess switching the sign-off without much information is a little cheeky. But the phrase "you get what you pay for" rings so true for the hosting industry. I wouldn't even dream of paying any less than that for any form of decent hosting, even at 5GB (and that's still a *lot* of space - my biggest footprint for a site is 1GB, which is miles out of the ordinary). Even Yoast (Joost de Valk) hosts with them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A host doesn't need to *specialize* in WordPress to be a good environment for it. Many hosts supposedly specialize in it, but don't provide any different features than their competitors. If you are looking for officially recommended hosts, take a look at the [WordPress recommended hosts](http://wordpress.org/hosting/). However, I'm not a fan of all of the hosts on that list.

Any **GOOD** web host that meet or exceeds the [minimum requirements](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/), has guaranteed uptime and keeps its customers happy, would be a good match. As a web developer, and having built over 100 WP sites, three of my favorite hosts include:

- [MediaTemple](http://mediatemple.net/) (Mid-priced)
- [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/) (Higher-priced)
- [HostGator](http://www.hostgator.com/) (Cheap)

I like the above hosts because of a combination of great features (and freedom for your developer to manipulate certain configuration options that other hosts do not allow), great customer service, and good, fast, reliable servers.

If you do decide on a host, add a comment and let us know which one you ultimately choose.

Comment: I have looked at these sites - thanks for the reccomendations. I prefer the look of gator, only reason is that they show their prices, I have no wisk to speak to sales teams in this instance as they will be trying to upsell all sorts of things.

Comment: While I have nothing against hosts listed by wordpress.org I must note that that list is likely paid advertisement or at the very least very subjective (as far as I know, Bluehost and Dreamhost seem to be common sponsors). While WP would work on any suitable hosting I strongly suggested (in discussion on meta) to make this question about hosts that **genuinely specialize** in WP so please let's steer towards that.

Comment: I have to disagree with MediaTemple, the grid servers are one of the worst hosting solutions out there, and this is especially true for WordPress installs due to the horrible sharded databases and resources (stay away, they are completely over hauling this entire service, since they know it's crap).

Answer (score 1):

Most hosting companies do nothing more than provide you with server space and a control panel which allows you to manage your account. Your host would typically not be answering questions regarding how to set up a new theme, installing plugins, or how to upload a PDF and add it to a post. Fortunately, these questions are answered on the internet.

It sounds like you might being looking for a web developer more than a host. If you need more involved help, this is were a web developer can help. Freelance websites like Elance.com or Fiverr.com allow you to ask for some professional help. Many web developers can assist you with finding a good host, but rather than trust them, webhostingtalk.com is a great place to ask around and search for reviews on webhosts.

Be warned, there are plenty of unscrupulous hosts out there that create their own 'review' websites on which they rank themselves as number one. Also, many web host review websites are paid advertisements, basically, who ever pays the most gets the top rank.

Regarding hosts, many Linux hosting servers have everything needed for Wordpress to run, so there normally isn't a need to insist that they specialize in Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you, I am not looking for a dev, stripped right back I am ultimately looking for the easiest host, with very quick installs etc.

Comment: cPanel hosts that have Fantastico have an easy way to install Wordpress. From inside the control panel, you click Fantastico, select Wordpress, hit install, and enter the admin and site details. It automatically installs the database and sets up the configuration for you. It might help if you go with a cPanel host.